# How to get the current location as longitude and latitude value

Tags: android, kotlin, location

I'm currently making a weather app and the **latitude** and **longitude** values could be used in the openweathermap API

So ***how do you get the user's current location by latitude and longitude values in kotlin?***

I already tried various method on the internet but none of them worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

This requires a lot of code, although most of it is for handling the Location permission. See here:

https://github.com/gavingt/SunCalculator/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/gavinsappcreations/sunrisesunsettimes/ui/MainActivity.kt